# facebook unity sdk internal compiler error

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Some combinations of parameters for FB.AppRequest causes an Internal Compiler Error.

E.g:

```
FB.AppRequest(
message:"This is the message",
title:"This is the the title",
callback:AppRequestResult);
```

But this is ok:

```
FB.AppRequest(
message:"This is the message",
callback:AppRequestResult);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is some know bug, have seen several posts. I would say to solve this, don't use named parameters for Facebook Sdk calls, since they bring all kinds of trouble.

Just look at the intelisense suggestions, and write up all the parameters (with "" and nulls if the fields don't apply to you). This worked perfectly for me and avoided Compiler Errors :)

Comment: That's correct.  Unity doesn't handle named parameters 100% correctly, especially with overloaded methods.